# is it possible to show an angular material's multi select component with initial value selected?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

In this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/ofertas/filtro-ofertas/filtro-ofertas.component.ts

I have a multi-select form control

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select formControlName="años" multiple placeholder="Años">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{year}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

[image: multiselect]

But I would like to mark as selected by Default the actual year, this is, 2021

```
export class FiltroOfertasComponent implements OnInit {
 private now:Date=new Date();
 actualYear:number=this.now.getFullYear();
 years:number[]=[this.actualYear-2, this.actualYear-1, this.actualYear];

 form: FormGroup;

 formularioOriginal = {
   años:[this.actualYear],
   fechaPresentada: '',
   descripcion: '',
   organismoId: 0,
   presentada: false,
   adjudicada: false
 }

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formularioOriginal);
```

but this doesn't show me the default selected value when setting the original form

This neither

```
formularioOriginal = {
años:this.actualYear,
fechaPresentada: '',
descripcion: '',
organismoId: 0,
presentada: false,
adjudicada: false
```

}

this neither

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formularioOriginal);

this.form.patchValue({
  años:this.actualYear
});
```

being a multi-select I don't know how to pass the initial value to it

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get following error message:

```
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode.
Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode.
```

There are two ways to pass a default value as array to the multi-select:

Either you patch the value after building the form:

```
this.form.patchValue({
 años: [this.actualYear]
});
```

Or you set the value in the form builder, in your code it would look like this:

```
 formularioOriginal = {
    años:[[this.actualYear]],
    fechaPresentada: '',
    descripcion: '',
    organismoId: 0,
    presentada: false,
    adjudicada: false
   }
```

As the formbuilder expects either a default value or an array (containing default value, validators, async validators), you need to use two sets of brackets to define an array as default value.
See example in the official Angular documentation here:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#validating-form-input

Comment: I've done in the form builder but I keep getting the same error. Thanks

Comment: You still get the error because after you set it in the form builder you try to patch it again not using an array.
See line 60 to 62 of that component in your stackblitz. I commented it out and it shows no error.

Comment: Ups sorry thanks yo very much great job

Comment: Now when I clean the form: this.form.patchValue(this.formularioOriginal); the selected value dissapear